# How to determine whether a set command failed to run in _vimrc?

Tags: vim

I added some set commands to my _vimrc file, how can I check whether the set command is executed successfully or not? I care about its status because there may be some different handling based on the status of previous set command.

Comment: Do you mean failure in a syntactic sense?

Comment: @RSahu, for example, set guifont will fail if the specified font doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to raise the value of the `verbose` option until you find a value that allows you to catch *every* error thrown by every option (and `set verbosefile=somefile` as well because your life will be miserable if you don't) but I suspect what you want can't really be done in a manageable manner and probably not worth the hassle.

Here are a couple of idioms that could help you, though:

**try something and catch errors**

```
try
    set option=value
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:EXXX/
    set option=othervalue
endtry
```

See `:help :try` and `:help :catch`.

Note that raising `verbose` to its maximum value didn't allow me to catch the `E596` error supposed to be thrown for invalid font so my point remains valid: it will be hard to find a silver bullet solution.

Also, `guifont` can take a coma-separated string as value so you can give it `n` fonts and let Vim use the first one that works.

**do something only if a feature is present**

```
  if has('mouse_sgr')
      set ttymouse=sgr
  endif
```

See `:help has()`.

If you gave us a concrete example of what you have in mind we could probably help you further.

Comment: Thanks. My specific requirement is setting guifont to a customized one, if it doesn't exist, set it to another one (both fonts are not the default one in gVim.)

Comment: You are right, it seems catch cannot get the failure of `set guifont=` here, the command following it will also not be interrupted. Anyway, specify comma separated fonts for gVim works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually handle exception in Vim.

In your case, this is an example:

```
for font in ['fonta:h10', 'fontb:h10', 'fontc:h10']
  if !get(s:, 'font_set')
    try
      execute 'set guifont='.font
      let s:font_set = 1
    catch
    endtry
  else
    break
  endif
endfor
```

For more details, refer `help :try`.